# How to display data on datagridview of Kendoui?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datagridview, kendo-ui

> How to display data on *datagridview* of kendo using my dataLayer **(DL)** ?, 
>     I also look on the documentation of telerik kendo, but I found it confusing?
>
> when I run the code below, it only shows the column's title.

**View**

> 

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<sampleProj.Model>() // Specify the type of the grid
    .Name("Grid")
    .BindTo((IEnumerable<sampleProj.Model>)ViewBag.Products)
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.FirstName);
        columns.Bound(p => p.LastName);
        columns.Bound(p => p.MName);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
    })
)
```

**Updated code with error**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid((List<MDL.Employee>)ViewData["oEmployees"])  
.Name("Grid")    
.Columns(columns => 
{        
    columns.Bound(p => p.Code).Title("Code");
    columns.Bound(p => p.FirstName).Title("First Name").Width(140);
    columns.Bound(p => p.LastName).Title("Last Name").Width(140);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Position).Title("Position").Width(100);
})
```

When I add the following properties this error depicts

> ***HttCompileException was unhandled by user code External component has thrown an exception***
>   and when I remove the code below, it displays the data grid view but no Action method

```
.ToolBar(toolbar => {
        toolbar.Create();
        toolbar.Save();
        toolbar.Custom();      
    })

    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource        
       .Ajax()         
       .Batch(true)
       .ServerOperation(false)
       .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
       .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Code))
       .Read(read => read.Action("dialogEmp_read", "MasterData"))
       .Create(update => update.Action("dialogEmp_Create", "MasterData"))
       .Update(update => update.Action("dialogEmp_Update", "MasterData"))
       .Destroy(update => update.Action("dialogEmp_Destroy", "MasterData"))

    )
```

Answer (score 1):

> You just have to follow this Process In the above process you are
>   missing your read method of Kendo Grid. so see following code in
>   Cshtml Page

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<sampleProj.Model.ListWhichYouAreBinding/StoredProcedure/ModelName>()
          .Name("GridName")
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
 columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Title("Name");
 columns.Bound(p => p.Phone).Title("Phone");
 columns.Bound(p => p.OtherValue).Title("Balance").Format({0:c}").HtmlAttributes(new
 {
  style = "text-align:right; padding-right: 11%;"
 });
 columns.Command(command => 
 { command.Destroy(); 
   command.Edit();
         }).Width(150);
        })
        .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Add New"))
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(0))
        .Sortable()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.GivePrimaryKeyFieldNAme);
            model.Field(p => p.GivePrimaryKeyFieldNAme).Editable(false);
        })

        .Create(update => update.Action("CreateRow", "ControllerName"))
       .Read(read => read.Action("GetData", "ControllerName", ))
        .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateRow", "ControllerName"))
      .Destroy(update => update.Action("DeleteRow", "ControllerName"))
         ))
```

> Now , In controller you have to create all the above methods for
>   **Read**,                **Update**, **Delete** and **Create**.
>   I will only tell you about read. Go in your controller and do this. 
>   Remember
>   Name of the function should be same which is written in

```
Read(read=>read.action in above)
```

> i.e GetData So, in controller make a function like this

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult GetData ([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
 {
 var YourData=Get Your List Here From Datatbase;
 return Json(YourData.ToDataSourceResult(request));
 }
```

**Hope This Will work For You.**

Comment: Thanks dude but what should I insert on **DataSource** and what's the rule of DataSource?  Thanks!

Comment: DataSource is what you are returning to grid or what you want to show in the grid. See the method in controller where YourData is receiving data from DB. You can call your Data from DB here. Like ObjDataContext.YourTable().Tolist(); and then give name of the Primary key field in your CSHtml Model.Id..

Comment: I do not know If I had understood your doubt and replied accordingly but You should try it once and Please mark my answer useful if it works for you.

Comment: when I'm adding those code on my project, error is popping up(See on the question).